# Class doesnt return correct variable c++

Tags: c++

Accounts.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Accounts
{
public:
    Accounts();
    void setUsername(string un){username = un;}
    void setPassword(string pw){username = pw;}
    void setLevel(int lv){username = lv;}


    string getUsername(){return username;}
    string getPassword(){return password;}
    int getLevel(){return level;}
private:
    string username;
    string password;
    int level;
};
```

This functions correctly reads file(i tested it). But whenever I try to get variable from that class, it gives me weird symbol and it doesnt work.

```
ifstream fin1("data/accounts/accounts.txt");
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; getline(fin1,line);i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            string username,password;
            int level;
            iss >> username >> password >> level;
            accounts[i].setUsername(username);
            accounts[i].setPassword(password);
            accounts[i].setLevel(level);
            cout << level << endl;
            cout << accounts[i].getLevel() << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which variable? What doesn't work? What is the input/ [expected] output of your program? How do you write to the file? To answer all of these questions, please provide [mcve].

Comment: "this function" ... there is no function, just some code. Plus, there is no `return`, so how would you expect to "get variable"?

Comment: Where is `accounts[]` defined?

Comment: Well, credit for actually using C++, unlike many (if not most) if the new posters here.  Points off for `using namespace std;` in a header file (no, I'm not going to downvote).  Having said that, what is `accounts`?  Is it a `std::vector` (hopefully)?

Comment: `void setPassword(string pw){username = pw;}`. That needs to be `password = pw;`. Similar error exists in `setLevel`.

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: `void setLevel(int lv){username = lv;}` this should be `void setLevel(int lv){level = lv;}
`

Comment: The same goes for setPassword, as some members already noted. The author of the code should take a closer look what his code does before asking for an explantion of the code behaviour. The program does exactly what the programer wrote. Returning values that are not expected but programed to return them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void setUsername(string un){username = un;}
void setPassword(string pw){username = pw;}
void setLevel(int lv){username = lv;}
```

The problem is in this lines of code. I believe, that it should be `void setLevel(int lv){level = lv;}`

Suggest fixing code to the following:

```
void setUsername(string un){username = un;}
void setPassword(string pw){password = pw;}
void setLevel(int lv){level = lv;}
```

Comment: @user4581301 thanks, updated.

Comment: How did this compile before? Does it call `std::string::operator=(char)` with the `int`?

Comment: @Kevin yes, you are probably right, though this question deserves another post on SO.

Comment: @Kevin Error message with a higher level of compiler paranoia  is `error: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]` so you've almost certainly nailed it.

Comment: @ig-melnyk Agreed. Kevin's question is the better of the two questions posed here.

Comment: I guess i shouldn't code late at evenings. I am so embarrassed right now :( . Thanks for answer anyways